# A matrix has only $0$'s in its diagonal, all the other entries are $1$'s. What are the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think that I should to rewrite the matrix in a appropriate form, but I can't find it. For a $2\times2$ matrix I get the characteristics polynomial $x^2-1$ and the eigenvalues $-1,1$. For $3\times3$ matrix I get $-x^3+3x+2$ and the eigenvalues are $2,-1,-1$.

Comment: In your matrix situation, for an n by n matrix, the eigenvalues are $n-1$ as well as $-1$ with multiplicity $n-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let A (your matrix) be
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1\\
1&0&1\\
1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
You can calculate the eigenvalues by calculating det(A - I$\lambda$) by using Cramer's rule.
\begin{equation}
A - I\lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda&1&1\\
1&-\lambda&1\\
1&1&-\lambda
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Doing this on the first row gives
\begin{equation}
0 = \operatorname{det}(A - I\lambda) = -\lambda (\lambda^2 -1) - 1(-\lambda -1) + 1(1 + \lambda)
\end{equation}
You can factor out $\lambda + 1$ and get the eigenvalues.

To get the eigenvectors you should, for each $\lambda$, solve the equation
\begin{equation}
A\vec{u}_i = \lambda_i\vec{u}_i
\end{equation}
since the eigenvectors of A are precisely those vectors who's direction remains unchanged when multiplied by A.
Solving this will give you a parametric solution for $\vec{u}_i$, so you can normalize it to get an explicit answer.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the answer was supposed to be for general $n$. However, I had to roll your post back to its original form, because it looked very strange as an answer otherwise. Mind you, some users will still find it strange that this answer was accepted. The onus for that falls, however, on the asker. There's nothing you can do about that. Actually, it may be a good idea to try and improve your answer (if you feel like it). But, no pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrix $B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ having $1$ in all entries. Then, it is clear that $\mathrm{rank}(B) = 1$ with $\ker(B) = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n)^t \in \mathbb{F}^n \, | \, x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 0 \}$ and $B(e_1 + \ldots + e_n) = n(e_1 + \ldots + e_n)$ where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors. Thus, the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $p_B(x) = \det(xI - B) = x^{n-1}(x - n)$ and the eigenspaces are

$$ V_0^B = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n)^t \in \mathbb{F}^n \, | \, x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 0 \}, \,\,\, V_n^B = \mathrm{span} \{ e_1 + \ldots + e_n \}. $$

Now, the matrix you are interested in is $A = B - I$ and so it has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 0 - 1 = -1$ and $\lambda_2 = n - 1$ with the same eigenspaces

$$ V_{-1}^A = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n)^t \in \mathbb{F}^n \, | \, x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 0 \}, \,\,\, V_{n-1}^A = \mathrm{span} \{ e_1 + \ldots + e_n \}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No; $\operatorname{rank}(B)=1$, independent of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo!